# How do I configure startx to start only Gnome Fallback session in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gnome, ubuntu-gnome, gnome-session-fallback

From a server install I want to be able to run `startx` and bring up the gnome-fallback-desktop.  I want to be able to log out and return to the command prompt.  This works currently with my configuration, but I can only bring up the gnome desktop.

I do not want to run lightdm if possible, because this will cause the logout to return to the login screen and I need it to return to the command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the key is to use `update-alternatives` to define the session.

Running  `update-alternatives --config x-session-manager` will list all of the sessions x-session-manager knows about and will allow you to choose which one to use.

In my case I set the session using this command.

```
update-alternatives --set x-session-manager /usr/lib/gnome-session-flashback
```